# How to fix my update statement in C# API?

Tags: c#, mysql, api

I wrote this below code and I am not able to update fields.

There is no error message, however my data is not getting updated.

```
public void UpdateTeacher(int id, [FromBody]Teacher TeacherInfo)
{
        MySqlConnection Conn = Teachers.AccessDatabase();

        //Open the connection between the web server and database.
        Conn.Open();

        //Establish a new command(query) for our database.
        MySqlCommand cmd = Conn.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "update teachers set teacherfname=TeacherFname, teacherlname=TeacherLname, employeenumber=EmployeeNumber,salary=Salary where teacherid=TeacherId";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeacherFname", TeacherInfo.TeacherFname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeacherLname", TeacherInfo.TeacherLname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeNumber", TeacherInfo.EmployeeNumber);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salary", TeacherInfo.Salary);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeacherId", id);
        cmd.Prepare();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Conn.Close();
}
```

I tried insert and delete, they are working, however update query is not working.

Comment: Change your update statement `set colname = @paramName`.

Comment: The code seems to use MySQL as the DB.  The tags reference sqlite,  Note that these are completely different dbs..  Also, `AddWithValue` is a *well documented` bad idea

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp There's no reason to avoid `AddWithValue` when using MySQL: https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/using-addwithvalue/

Answer (score 2):

If you look at how you are adding your parameters, you stated that the parameter name starts with an '@' symbol.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeacherFname", TeacherInfo.TeacherFname);
...
```

But if you look at your SQL text, you have not used the '@' symbol, so you need to add this at the front of all your parameter names.

```
 cmd.CommandText = "update teachers set teacherfname=@TeacherFname, teacherlname=@TeacherLname, employeenumber=@EmployeeNumber,salary=@Salary where teacherid=@TeacherId";
```

As also stated in the comments, using `AddWithValue` is generally considered bad.  See this for more details:
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: also suggest OP to use `using` with the connection

Comment: There's no reason to avoid `AddWithValue` when using MySQL: https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/using-addwithvalue/